# HttpContext.Session SetString() and GetString() not exisit after passing HttpContext from controller to BL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I'm using .net core,trying to pass HttpContext or HttpContext.Session to BL to do some work.

The problem is while in the controller i'm having access no problem to:

HttpContext.Session.SetString("SomeKey", "SomeValue")
After the passing - the method just not exist....

In Controller:

```
result = await someBL.doSomeWork(id, HttpContext);
```

And then in BL:

```
public async Task<bool> doSomeWork(int id, HttpContext httpContext)
        {
             httpContext.Session.SetString....//method not exist
```

Also tried injecting the IHttpContextAccessor and got the same exact result.

please help :)

Comment: Is there a `using` directive for [the namespace of those extention methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions.setstring)?  Though taking a step back... Coupling a non-application layer to application-specific technologies probably isn't a good idea.  Ideally you'd transform the data into a domain-common structure that your other layers can understand.

Comment: @David yes there is: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the method does not exist is because the context objects are not of the same type in the Controller and in the Bl class.

The session in the context accessed in the controller is inherited from the Controller class which inherits it from the ControllerBase class, and it has some extra extension methods.
In your case the .SetString is one such extension method.

Its implementation is the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets a <see cref="string"/> value in the <see cref="ISession"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="session">The <see cref="ISession"/>.</param>
/// <param name="key">The key to assign.</param>
/// <param name="value">The value to assign.</param>
public static void SetString(this ISession session, string key, string value)
{
    session.Set(key, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
}
```

While the session you get from the IHttpContextAccessor is the base implementation of ISession and it has only the Set method which takes a byte array as its value when setting key, value pairs.

You can achieve your goal in the Bl class by using the following code:

```
string theWork = "work work work work nananana";
byte[] theWorkBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theWork);
_httpContext.HttpContext.Session.Set("someWork", theWorkBytes);
```

And then read it in one of the following ways based on where you need it:

```
// In a controller
string theWorkString = HttpContext.Session.GetString("someWork");

// From IHttpContextAccessor
byte[] theWorkBytes = HttpContext.Session.Get("someWork");
string theWork = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(theWorkBytes);
```

I would recommend not passing the context as an argument. But, rather getting the context from DI in the constructor.

Comment: Hi thx man, i was loosing my mind over this and chatGpt didn't help too.
So it's work perfectly but the only thing to change in your answer that HttpContext.Session.Get doesn't exist in IHttpContextAccessor so i used HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue that exist there.
Thx again.